# Why do Australian states have different rules for senate voting to the federal government?

Tags: voting, australia

There seems to be a difference in rules for voting for the states and the federal government in Australia. For example, in the state of Victoria, you only have to enter 1 preference in the top line on the Senate ticket wherein the federal election you need to enter 6 preferences.

Answer (score 3):

The short version is that Australian states still have separate parliaments, 
and that means the parliaments can decide independently what election method the voters of that parliament use to elect it.

BTW: before 2016, the Federal Senate actually voted in the same way as the Victorian Legislative Council (as the senate is called in Victoria.)